# google drive options is not visible in UIDocumentMenuViewController in IOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, uidocumentinteraction, uidocumentmenuvc

We have developed chat application and in that app there is one feature of file sharing like whatsapp, Its all working fine in up to `iOS9.x`, but when I test it in `iOS10`, google drive option immediately disappear.

That is what I am trying to describe in the case
Tried to send a file,but the google drive dissapear before I even get to select it.

Here is the steps taken before the bug happens :- 
•On chat 
•Select "Send File" 
•Select "More" 
•Able to see "Google Drive" for half second before it dissapear(See Attached photo) Options

But up to iOS9.x we there a option of google drive. I search lot on google and on Stackoverflow but Can't find any solution about iOS specific.

we write following code for this:

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *documentProviderMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[(NSString*)kUTTypeCompositeContent] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
documentProviderMenu.delegate = self;
documentProviderMenu.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:documentProviderMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
```

new edit:

I get one thing, its hide by `UIDocumentMenuViewController` because see in second image, if I drag row upside then its appear and google drive available in row number -1. If I re arrange it then I can get it in second row, but first row is disappear by default (not displaying in the screen).

I apply following things but not succeeded.

http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5065803028234240

http://openradar.appspot.com/19385063

http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6144449704886272

http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6144449704886272

Please any one tell me what is the issue? Thanks in advance...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced the same issue. I was able to solve the issue by making navigation bar translucent. You may also use

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
```

This appears to be a bug and there is also a similar issue reported here http://www.openradar.me/24564847

Comment: I can confirm this is working. What problems can this workaround cause in other screens in an application?

Comment: @Steeve Thank you for the confirmation. The issue is noticeable only if the navigation bar is not translucent. Before launching the UIDocumentMenuVC calling the appearance proxy to set the navigation bar translucent as mentioned above will definitely solve the issue by making the navigation bar of UIDocumentMenuVC translucent. However, there is a possibility of also turning your app's non-translucent navigation bar to translucent which you will have to take care of in some cases. I have not faced any such kind of issue with this workaround in my app so far.